# Ruby on Rails ob_start to remove HTML line break?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, replace, word-wrap, ob-start

When using PHP in a simple HTML page like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I could use `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` and then `str_replace` the `\n` to do something like:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

saving the document size in order to make the webpage load faster.

I was just wondering if that is possible in the Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Don't bother too much on stripping white space, but use gzip compression first and see if you gain some better loading speed then.

Comment: when the webpage is large this is an useful method to make page load faster and smaller,you can view google homepage source

Comment: So, why don't you minify it before sending something to the client (which is suppressed by `ob_*` functions). Just do a string- or regex-replace on the output before it is send. Anyway this is not a PHP, but a Ruby question.

Comment: the processing overhead of removing the newlines will probably vastly exceed any bandwidth savings you might achieve.